# How can I add an "or" operation to the loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, logical-operators

I want to loop the code below. How can I keep the column names in the array and return by loop?

```
 return Students.filter((singleItem) => {

   singleItem["id"].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
   singleItem["name"].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
   singleItem["class"].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())

  });
```

For example:

```
  var columns= ["id","name","class"];

  return Students.filter((singleItem) => {
   columns.map(data=>{

   singleItem[data].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()); //I have to use the "||" operation here. How can I use it in the loop?
  
   })

 });
```

Comment: Just add it where you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the given keys and exit early with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var columns = ["id", "name", "class"];

return Students.filter(singleItem =>
    ["id", "name", "class"].some(key =>
        singleItem[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    )
);
```